# How to properly format several terminal commands for execution using Python os.system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, sudo, os.system

I'd like to run some terminal commands in my Python script using `os.system`. I'm not sure how to properly format these, particularly when using `sudo -i` because when run independently with `os.system("sudo -i")` it waits for user input rather than using the subsequent commands.

Here's my attempt which unsurprisingly returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`:

```
commands = "sudo -i && \
            rmmod ftdi_sio  && \
            rmmod usbserial  && \
            modprobe ftdi-sio  && \
            echo -n VENDOR_ID PRODUCT_ID | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id  && \
            stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb  && \
            echo -e "SOME_STRING" > /dev/ttyUSB0  && \
            apt install screen  && \
            screen /dev/ttyUSB0"

os.system(commands)
```

How might I modify this run successfully without syntax errors?

Comment: use `'''` or `"""` for outer quoting: `cmd = '''echo 'hello'; echo "world"; '''`

Comment: I would recommend using https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html instead

Comment: Ok great. So I can see that `subprocess.run(["sudo", "-i"])` works but how would I run commands within this root session?

Comment: @Pyy : You try to assign a string which basically looks like `"...."SOME_STRING"...."`. This is simply an invalid string literal in Python.  See [here](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/string_literals.html)  how to write strings in Python.

Comment: @Pyy : Since you want to run a somewhat complex command sequence by the shell, I would write a shell script for this, and invoke the script from Python: I think this would also make debugging easier, because you don't mix Shell and Python code in a single source file.

Comment: That does sound useful. I've formatted all commands as you suggest and debugging is slightly confusing. I'm trying to connect to a usb serial device and stream data from it. The terminal commands in my initial question do this with the `screen` command so I'm trying to see this working through python so I see that I can get the connection and try to use pySerial to bring the data into a variable for manipulation.